# gcc compiler options with complex.h

Tags: c++, gcc

I compiled a program in CodeBlocks (which uses gcc) and it was working fine.
Now I tried to compile the same program using gcc from command line. it produced this error:

```
error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

for these four lines :

```
OutArray[Index[g]].real() = TempVBF.FirstReal[g];
OutArray[Index[g]].imag() = TempVBF.FirstImag[g];
OutArray[Index[g]+ElementSize].real() = TempVBF.SecondReal[g];
OutArray[Index[g]+ElementSize].imag() = TempVBF.SecondImag[g];
```

in these line I've four values containing real and imaginary parts of 2 complex numbers. and I'm assigning those values to 2 complex variables.
I tried to do it like this:

```
OutArray[Index[g]] = (TempVBF.FirstReal[g],TempVBF.FirstImag[g]);
```

that compiled but generated wrong values in run time

why did it compile first but not now ?? what option can i use to get around this without changing those lines ??

I'm using the command :

```
gcc lib/Globals.cpp lib/Comp/SNT_FFT_Comp.cpp lib/Comp/ST_FFT_Comp.cpp lib/Comp/VNT_FFT_Comp.cpp lib/Comp/VT_FFT_Comp.cpp lib/Decomp/* test/main.cpp -lpthread -std=gnu++0x -o TEST
```

removing `-std=gnu++0x` produces a lot more errors . changing it to `-std=c++0x` changes nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're seeing is almost certainly because `real()` and `imag()` return the value of the real or imaginary part; not a reference to it. Without seeing the code, it's impossible to know for sure, but it would be much more likely to be defined like this:

```
double real() const { return this->_real; }
```

than like this:

```
double& real() { return this->_real; }
```

With the latter case, you could use the reference to perform an assignment. With the former case, you have a copy of the real part of your complex number, and you can't change your complex number with that. You can [read more about lhvalues and rhvalues](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/15/understanding-lvalues-and-rvalues-in-c-and-c/) if you want.

As for why it didn't work in the first place, that's almost impossible to answer. The code you provided seems to be missing a type -- in other words, it looks like you should do something like this:

```
OutArray[Index[g]] = MyComplexNumberClass(TempVBF.FirstReal[g],TempVBF.FirstImag[g]);
```

Why the values are wrong could be due to a great many things (memory stomps, the index "g" being wrong, the complex numbers not having the values you think they should have, etc). To debug that, you can try printing the value of things step by step until you see something you don't expect, either with `std::cerr` or [by using gbd](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/03/debug-c-program-using-gdb/).